# How do I change the domain when using URL::action()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to duplicate something that was available in Laravel 3. I want to be able to specify an alternate domain name for a route. For example, I have a route that produces the following with this code:

```
URL::action('DashboardController@something')
// Produces: http://somedomain.com/dashboard/something
```

I want to be able to specify a different domain. This used to be in the config/application.php file as 'url'. This no longer works in L4.

Is there a way to specify a base url to use whenever a URL is being constructed?

Comment: Should this route have the same domain permanently or just in one specific case?

Comment: It should be permanent for any URL generated by the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel 4 uses the Domain specified in the HTTP Request Header Field `Host`, e.g. `Host: http://foo.dev`.

If you want a different domain name, try something like this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'bar.dev'), function()
{
    Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');
});
```

Now `URL::action('HomeController@getWelcome');`returns `https://bar.dev/home/welcome` instead of `https://foo.dev/home/welcome`

Answer (score 1):

The location of the "app"-directory is defined in: \bootstrap\paths.php
The default location of config file is now: \app\config\app.php

Depending on your setup, it should be around line 29 in app.php.

Look for:

```
'url' => 'http://somedomain.com',
```

And change this to whatever suits your website.

Comment: This doesn't work in Laravel 4. This config value is only used when running in console mode through artisan.

Comment: At first I didn't get when to use of this `url` setting. But now I do. You need to do this if you have created some Artisan console tool that runs any script whereby the a url generating function such as `url()` generates a link to the website reason being because from the CLI there's no way to determine the top level domain of the server running the script i.e. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is empty. So this worked for me since I created an Artisan command that sends emails to people and within those emails are embedded links to the website created by `url()` function. Hope that clarifies things.