# Change Route Domain to IP address in Laravel

Tags: php, url, laravel-4

I want to know how would I change the **base url** of laravel to IP address. Im using localhost and instead of `http://localhost`, i want it to be `http://127.0.0.1`. Changing the URL property on app/config/app.php is not the solution since [that setting is only used for console command (artisan).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948595/how-do-i-change-the-domain-when-using-urlaction)

What im trying to attain is to make this link value:

```
{{ HTML::style('assets/images/favicon.ico', array('rel' => 'icon', 'type' => 'image/x-icon')); }}
```

which is:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" media="all" href="http://local/apps/myapp/public/assets/images/favicon.ico">
```

to:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" media="all" href="http://127.0.0.1/apps/myapp/public/assets/images/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There exists at least two ways to override the **base URL**. Either directly in your blade view:

```
{{ HTML::style('http://127.0.0.1/assets/images/favicon.ico'); }}
```

Or in your *routes.php* you have access to the **URL facade** which provides the **forceRootUrl** method:

```
URL::forceRootUrl('http://127.0.0.1');
```

With that can declare the **base URL** globally by placing it on top of your *routes.php*:

```
URL::forceRootUrl('http://127.0.0.1'); // all your routes are declared below this point.

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

Or even locally for a single route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    URL::forceRootUrl('http://127.0.0.1');
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

Comment: for the second option, is it global once i declare it? can you please show how exact to use it in routes.php..thank you :D

Comment: i have problem, `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::forceRootUrl()`..how is it?

Comment: Please update your Laravel installation. The feature was added with **4.2.0**. [see commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/d4ef5b200985206b2e09aa409a2901ff44605a61).